# Need help with jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to get the jquery ui autocomplete to work with a codeigniter project.

so far I have an input field `<input type="text" id="text1"/>`

and then in my script I have

```
source: function(request, response) {
            $.post('autocompleteHandler', {mechanic: request.term}, function(data) {
            console.log('data.phpResp = '+data.phpResp);
            console.log('in post?');

            console.log('data = '+data.toSource);

            var realArray = $.makeArray(data);  // this line was needed to use the $.map function

            response($.map(realArray, function(item) {

                console.log('in map');

                return {
                    label: item.info,
                    value: item.info
                }

            }));


            }, 'json');
        },
```

In my codeigniter controller I have this function

```
function autocompleteHandler() {

    $input = $this->input->post('mechanic');

    $this->load->model('login_model');

    $results = $this->login_model->search_mechanic_criteria($input);

    $mechs= array();
    foreach($results as $result) {

        $mechs['info'] = $result['mechanic_name'];  

    }
}
```

I'm not getting this to work. anyone have any ideas of where I can begin to troubleshoot? I really have a hard time with the jquery ui documentation.

**EDIT**: I've changed my code a bit. Instead of returning json_encode, I needed to echo json_encode on the php side of things. I still don't have anything showing up in my console though.

**2ND EDIT** Now my question is, how can I return multiple values for the autocomplete function? If i have a query that returns, just one row, it works fine, but if I have multiple rows returned, doesn't work. It's gotta be something with the way i'm returning the data, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please check http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/, i believe you're not returning the right format from PHP. Use firebug to see the ajax content returned.

Comment: I'm not using that plugin. I'm using the jquery ui autocomplete plugin.

Comment: did you try fiddler to see what the server was producing?

Comment: I don't need fiddler, I can just use the net console in firebug. I can see that the server is returning what i'm expecting.

Comment: For the 2ND EDIT question, see http://jsfiddle.net/XYMGT/1/. It is a matter of returning an array of objects instead of just an object, at least while speaking client side. Server side it is properly a matter of using "$mechs[] = $result['mechanic_name'];" instead of "$mechs['info'] = $result['mechanic_name'];".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been playing around with jsfiddle after you mentioned toSource(). See http://jsfiddle.net/XYMGT/. I find that the map function does not return jQuery, but the new array.

**OLD STUFF:**

<del>I suspect that the $.map function does not return the array, but jQuery. Maybe it would to do this:</del>

```
            // also you could inspect the data if the server returns what you think it returns:
            console.log(data);

            // first map the array
            $.map(data, function(item) {

                console.log('in response?');


                return {
                    label: 'testing',
                    value: 'test'
                }
            })
            // ...then separately do the response part
            response(data);
```

Lets us know if it makes a difference.

EDIT:

If this PHP code is still used:

```
function autocompleteHandler() {
  echo json_encode(array('phpResp' => 'something'));
}
```

Then console.log(data) should show the following in the console tab in FireBug:

```
{'phpResp':'somehting'}
```

Meaning that console.log(data.phpResp) should print 'something'. I am unsure where you are getting data.toSource from.

Comment: Good, what about the first console.log statement, what did it print? undefined, null, [] or the expected data?

Comment: if I change it from `console.log(data);` to `console.log(data.toSource);`, it prints `undefined`.

Comment: `console.log(data.phpResp)` prints `something` as expected. `toSource` is a way to view the data of an object in js.

Comment: I've updated my question with new code that works most of the way. Check it out and see if you can help me with my current problem.

Comment: I figured it out from this link. Inside my foreach loop, I just needed this line - `array_push($mechs, array('info'=>$result['mechanic_name']));`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would launch [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see what it says it's returning. You can also go straight to your server side page in the browser that is serving the JSON results. I think the autocomplete automatically adds `?term` to the string. `url.aspx?term=|valueofText1|`

```
$("#text1").autocomplete({
    source: url,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        sou = ui.item.label;
    }
});
```